# how to replace space with '-' when they are more than 2 words

Tags: php

When i use the following code, the space is getting displayed only for the starting word

i.e if i use

`replace(' ','-',true)`

for the word

`2 wheeler parking`

I am getting output as `2-wheeler parking`.

The `'space'` is not replaced by `'-'` before parking.

what should I use to get the `'-'` before every word

Comment: "*when i use the following code*" — Where is your code? Did you forget to paste it?

Comment: can you please tell me from where did you get this function `replace()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Surely you can just use [`str_replace()`](https://www.php.net/str_replace):

```
$old = '2 seater parking';
$newString = str_replace(' ', '-', $old);
```

The above code produces `2-seater-parking`. [**Demo**](https://eval.in/119432)